# jQuery .change() fails on input type="file"

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

This doesn't work

```
<input type="file" id="foo" />
...
$("#foo").change(function() { alert('bing') });
```

but this does

```
<input type="file" id="foo" onchange="alert('bing')" />
```

Element id values are unique.

Am I using jQuery incorrectly or is there a problem with input type="file"?

I notice that knockout **value**  binding doesn't seem to work on input type="file" forcing me to explicitly bind a change handler to update the view model. (Since reading Arun's comment about binding too early I tried letting KO data-bind for the change event. That *works*, which is handy but unexpected given that the original problem was KO's failure to data-bind for value.)

```
<!-- in view -->
<input type="file" id="inputFile" data-bind="event: {change: choseFile}" />
<button class="button" data-bind="click: chooseFile">Select the file</button>
<textarea readonly="readonly" data-bind="text: newUpload.fileName" />

//in view model
return {
  history: history,
  newUpload: newUpload,
  choseFile: function () { newUpload.fileName($("#inputFile").val()); },
  chooseFile: function () { $("#inputFile").click(); },
};
```

As you can see from the sample, I have addressed the old conundrum of `input type="file"` failure to respond to CSS by hiding it entirely and using proxy widgets.

[image: Restyled file input]

In particular it handles long paths much better.

Comment: It means when the either when the event handler is registered the input element is not yet added to the dom or there are multiple elements with the said id

Comment: try `$(document).on('change', '#foo', function(){alert('bing')})`

Comment: ok that makes sense for the JQ problem but what about KO? It works on every other input type.

Comment: is there multiple file elements with the same id?

Comment: Element ids are unique.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  $("#foo") to find  if there is not multiple  elements.

Please see below. it is work on my local.

```
$("#foo").on('change', function(){

    alert('we change the file');

})
```

Maybe it is JQ issue

Comment: I ended up solving this by using knockout to data-bind a handler to the change event of the `<input type="file">`, the handler simply updating the model. Since KO depends on JQ I surmise that Arun is correct about trying to bind before the DOM has been rendered; this is likely because the "page" is a Durandal view and the code is in the view model construction.